Cisco API rest ISE call with filtering shows total of 6 but only 1 ressource due to case-sensitivity
Calling ISE with the following command: /ers/config/networkdevice/filter=name.contains.xxxx
Which gives me for ex. following cutout:

{'SearchResult': 'total': 6{'resources': [{'description': 'Switch',
                                 'id': 'f12fcb10-8e71-11e8-88d7-de5b9335be65',
                                 'link': {'href': 'https://x.x.x.x:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/xxxxx',
                                          'rel': 'self',
                                          'type': 'application/json'},
                                 'name': 'xxxxx'}],
                  }}

The problem is, that this way of searching finds a total of 6, but due to the case-sensitve filtering(filter=name.xxx) it only shows 1 results.
Results with a name like: XXxx or xXxx etc. are not shown. How can I make sure I see all 6 results, so also xxXx etc. ?
